# PHPExcel - read data of 2 columns

Tags: php, phpexcel

I want to get value of cells for several rows in a xls file with PHPExcel but it doesn't work.
I want to read from line 22 at the end and get value of columns B and C of the row.

This is my code :

```
// Ouvre avec PHPExcel
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($fichier);

// Feuille active
$sheetObj = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

// Parcours des lignes à partir de la 22
foreach($sheetObj->getRowIterator(22,null) as $row){
    $num_colis = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow('B', $row)->getValue();
    $num_commande = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow('C', $row)->getValue(); 
}
```

Comment: try phpExcel toArray() described in http://hitautodestruct.github.io/PHPExcelAPIDocs/classes/PHPExcel_Worksheet.html#method_toArray e.g. $objPHPExcel->getSheetByName('tab1')->toArray()

Comment: Which line I must change to this ?

Comment: after ::load($fichier); $laArray = ...toArray(); and then work with $laArray.

Comment: Okay but in $IaArray, I can't do getCellByColumnAndRow() method and I have 29 arrays in $IaArray that corresponds at number of rows of the xls file.

Comment: so $laArray[21][1] should be the value of row22 column B, i think, not sure if it the index starts from 0

Comment: And what does not work with the given code?

Answer (score 0):

```
$num_colis = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('B1:C1')->getValue(); //array
$num_colis = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B1')->getValue(); // string
```

Also you can do this to read cell in specific column dynamically:

```
$num = your num row
$num_colis = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B'.$num)->getValue(); // string
```

Your loop must look like this:

```
$num = 22;
foreach($sheetObj->getRowIterator(22 ,null) as $row){
    $num_colis = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B'.$num)->getValue();
    $num_commande = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C'.$num)->getValue(); 
    $num++;
}
```